# Which widget should I choose to achieve the needs in the picture

Tags: qt

[image]

I'm implementing an icon button. Click it to pull down several options. The left side of the selection is an image and the right side is text. I'm considering which widget can implement this function. Is it QDialog or QComboBox? A little instruction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most native way would be to use a button with popup menu:

1. Use a `ToolButton`,
2. Set its `toolButtonStyle` to `ToolButtonIconOnly`,
3. Set its `popupMode` to `InstantPopup`,
4. Setup a custom QMenu with your actions (with icons and text),
5. Attach the menu to the button with `setMenu`.

All this is well documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtWidgets/QToolButton.html).